# How to SUM account_ID by Unit_ID and provide SUM Total Amount with Balance Total

Tags: sql, ssms, ssms-2016

Would like to know why my query does not roll up and sum all "ID_Number", with individual  "Product_ID", "Total_Receipts" Aging?

Created query with SQL Server Management Studio, my output to display correctly has parameters, and I have tried the following with my query.

```
Totals:
    count(ar.Product_ID) AS 'Total_Receipts'
    sum(ar.Receipt_Amount) AS 'Total_Amount',
    sum(chg.Balance) AS 'Total Balance'
```

Currently my SQL SSMS query output displays the following:

```
ID_Number  Production_ID  Total_Receipts  Aging          Month   Year    Total_Amount  Total Balance
0017       105206         143             90 DAYS PLUS   April   2021    $357.00       $357.00
0017       105206         143             90 DAYS PLUS   April   2021    $380.00       $380.00
0017       105343         132             90 DAYS PLUS   April   2021    $330.00       $330.00
0017       105343         132             90 DAYS PLUS   April   2021    $351.00       $351.00
```

What I really would like is to have a specific output that provides "Production_ID" and consolidate by each "ID_Number", then "Total sum with AGING" and SUM receipt charges "Total_Amount" like listed below:

```
ID_Number  Production_ID  Total_Receipts  Aging          Month   Year    Total_Amount  Total Balance
0017       105206         143             90 DAYS PLUS   April   2021    $737.00       $737.00
0017       105343         132             90 DAYS PLUS   April   2021    $681.00       $681.00
```

[Query]

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE DATETIME2
DECLARE @ENDDATE DATETIME2

SET @STARTDATE = '2021-01-01 00:00:00'
SET @ENDDATE = '2022-02-10 00:00:00'

SELECT DISTINCT

te.ID_Number AS 'ID_Number',
chg.product_ID,
count(ar.Product_ID) AS 'Total_Receipts'


,CASE
   WHEN DATEDIFF(day, chg.Created_Date, @EndDate) < 30 THEN 'CURRENT'
   WHEN DATEDIFF(day, chg.Created_Date, @EndDate) BETWEEN 30 AND 59 THEN '30 DAYS'
   WHEN DATEDIFF(day, chg.Created_Date, @EndDate) BETWEEN 60 AND 89 THEN '60 DAYS'
   WHEN DATEDIFF(day, chg.Created_Date, @EndDate) >= 90 THEN '90 DAYS PLUS'
 END AS 'Aging',
   DATENAME(MONTH, chg.Created_Date) AS 'Month',
   DATEPART(YEAR, chg.Created_Date) AS 'Year',
   sum(ar.Receipt_Amount) AS 'Total_Amount',
   sum(chg.Balance) AS 'Total Balance'


 FROM  dbo.charges AS chg
 LEFT JOIN dbo.ar_receipts AS ar  
 ON arcpts.production_ID = chg.production_ID 
 INNER JOIN dbo.entities AS te
 ON buld.Name = te.Name
 INNER JOIN dbo.Employee AS emp
 ON ar.Charge_ID = emp.Charge_ID 

 WHERE
 chg.Balance > 0 AND
 chg.Created_Date >= @STARTDATE AND 
 chg.Created_Date <= @ENDDATE 

 GROUP BY
 te.ID_Number,
 chg.Created_Date,
 chg.product_ID

 ORDER BY
 te.ID_Number,
 Datename(month,chg.Created_Date)
```

Comment: group by te.ID_Number, chg.product_ID  and aggregate all the rest columns wanted as needed.

Comment: @Serg, problem with aggregate all as you suggested, would you have additional syntax programming demonstration?

Comment: Order by the actual date column and not the month. That makes more sense and also won't cause problems when your range spans multiple years.

Comment: There's absolutely zero reason to use `select distinct` here. If you happened to have two dates (herein reduced to month/year) with the same summary values you'd still want it listed twice.

Comment: The answer to your question is because of the `group by <date>`. Each row represents different dates within the month. So you need to either group and month and year or collapse all dates to a single representative (like the first of the month.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you can aggregate columns with max

```
SELECT 

te.ID_Number AS ID_Number,
chg.product_ID,
count(ar.Product_ID) AS Total_Receipts


,max(CASE
   WHEN DATEDIFF(day, chg.Created_Date, @EndDate) < 30 THEN 'CURRENT'
   WHEN DATEDIFF(day, chg.Created_Date, @EndDate) BETWEEN 30 AND 59 THEN '30 DAYS'
   WHEN DATEDIFF(day, chg.Created_Date, @EndDate) BETWEEN 60 AND 89 THEN '60 DAYS'
   WHEN DATEDIFF(day, chg.Created_Date, @EndDate) >= 90 THEN '90 DAYS PLUS'
 END) AS max_Aging,
   max(DATENAME(MONTH, chg.Created_Date)) AS max_Month,
   max(DATEPART(YEAR, chg.Created_Date)) AS max_Year,
   sum(ar.Receipt_Amount) AS Total_Amount,
   sum(chg.Balance) AS Total_Balance


 FROM  dbo.charges AS chg
 LEFT JOIN dbo.ar_receipts AS ar  
 ON arcpts.production_ID = chg.production_ID 
 INNER JOIN dbo.entities AS te
 ON buld.Name = te.Name
 INNER JOIN dbo.Employee AS emp
 ON ar.Charge_ID = emp.Charge_ID 

 WHERE
 chg.Balance > 0 AND
 chg.Created_Date >= @STARTDATE AND 
 chg.Created_Date <= @ENDDATE 

 GROUP BY
 te.ID_Number, chg.product_ID

 ORDER BY
 te.ID_Number, chg.product_ID
```

Comment: one additional problem, syntax with aggregate columns with max listed ID_Number correctly. "chg.product_ID" and all other columns repeated and listed duplicates.

Comment: @Rob_Q,  .. oops, forget to drop `chg.Created_Date` from `group by`. Corrected.

Comment: disregard my last comment!  I removed from GROUP BY "chg.Created_Date," all listed duplicates have been removed after running your Query with aggregate columns with max. Thank YOU